ubuntu slow copy of files from external NVME to internal SSD
I have an external NVME 3.2 drive which gives read write speed of around 1 Giga Byte/second on my macbook air.
But when I connect that same drive to my desktop which have USB 3.1 port and an internal sata ssd then copying speed from nvme to ssd starts fine like around 500 MBPS but slows down immediately and keeps dropping I have seen speed dropping to around 10 MB/s.
Moreover the RAM gets full (24 GB) on HTOP (mostly cached) and system also slows down a lot, like even keyboard inputs take seconds to appear.
Tried tweaking these proc values based on some recommendation like so.
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes

and in process monitor it shows burst read and write to disks in burst.
I mean read and write speed is mostly around 5-10 MBps and then suddenly shots up to around 200-300 MBps for a second or two then again goes down and stays mostly around 9 MBps.
Mac however maintains steady around 1 gigabyte/second read and write speed on the same drive, So the controller of the device is not the problem, device is also not hot to touch when using on ubuntu, it heats up a little when on MAC.
There is also no driver issue in ubuntu as it is reading from the drive at higher speed but not consistently, also it is somehow caching the file in RAM and preferring it even more than the actual OS files and hence slowing down when copying large amount of data, CPU usage stays around 5%, so no bottleneck there. external nvme ssd, the enclosure, USB port and even SATA drive has sufficient bandwidth to allow reading and writing at at least 350 MB/s.
I have also tested by copying one large file and multiple small files and result is consistently slow in both the cases.
Drive is formatted in exFAT.
Tried switching the USB port multiple times.
lsusb --tree shows the drive is connected to correct port and connection speed is 10000M

Search this site for "slow copy" or "transfer rate" and see the many questions/suggestions, some of which might help specific situations. Any time the write rate is slower than the read rate, system buffers fill up and the system slows down.
